# Using 'endl' in C++ programming

Tags: c++, endl

1. first code

```cpp
#include <studio.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "apple" << endl << "banana";
}
```

2. second code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    cout << "apple" << endl;
    cout << "banana" << endl;
}
```

Why am i wrong?
i know the answer is second one,
But i want to know the why my first code is wrong.
Please help me!

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: What do you mean by you know the answer is the second one? What's the code required to do?

Comment: `#include <studio.h>`? There is a "stdio.h", but it's a C header.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n

Comment: did you read the compilers error message?

Answer (score 8):

This first code is wrong because `#include <studio.h>` is the wrong header file. The correct header file for `std::cout` and `std::endl` is `#include <iostream>`.

It's also wrong because `endl` is in the `std::` namespace. So even with the correct header file it should be `std::endl`

```
std::cout << "apple" << std::endl << "banana";
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put **std::** before **endl** in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the doc: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl

as you can see, 2 important things are related to the error/question you posted:

1. `endl` is defined in header `<ostream>`
2. it is in the namespace `std`

so it must be used as `std::endl`
note that the ostream is a parent of the iostream so including the iostream guaranties you have access to the ostream

[image]

Comment: omg... what a kind explanation ! I didn't understand ios but I just used it. Now i understand basic definition of ios thanks to you (: